# MySQL - Can I use a variable in place of a column name in SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have following code snippet to implement a multilingual website. 
Idea is to, depending on user's language i need to translate word "Man" to "Hombre"

My Question: Will it be valid to use $user_language instead of hard coded column name "Spanish" here.

code:
      //$user_language (Spanish in this case) is passed from his profile after log in to the site

```
  SELECT $user_language 
  FROM TranslationTable 
  WHERE English=Man
```

TranslationTable:

```
  English     Spanish   French
  Man          Hombre    homme
```

Thanks
SW

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can use variables like this, but you could construct your query using Dynamic SQL.

However, if you have the opportunity to change your table structure, that might be a better option for you.  I'd recommend breaking this apart into the following tables:

```
Language (store your languages such as English, Spanish, etc):
LanguageId and LanguageName

LanguageTranslation (language translation lookup table):
LanguageId, TokenId, and Translation

Token (store your tokens - versus querying directly on the english translation):
TokenId and TokenName
```

Then you could easily query it like such:

```
SELECT Translation
FROM LanguageTranslation LT
   JOIN Language L ON LT.LanguageId = L.LanguageId
   JOIN Token T ON LT.TokenId = T.TokenId
WHERE L.LanguageName = 'Spanish'
    AND T.TokenName = 'Man'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that should be a problem. I have used variables (database field prefix according to language selected) in column selection process and it has worked for me.

Try it and if it doesn't work, put your variables in braces {} and you should be OK

Answer (score 0):

You can (it's just a string after all), but you need to be wary of injection - make sure you've filtered the variable prior to substitution (`filter_var` works quite well:http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).